# Get Selenium Element from Watir Element

Tags: watir

This might seem like a strange request, but here goes anyhow.
Using Watir, I find an element.

Example element:
`"#<Watir::Div: located: false; {:id=>\"searchFieldOptions\", :tag_name=>\"div\"}>"`

One of the external tools I'm wishing to use only supports Selenium elements.
Is there a way to get a Selenium element from the Watir element?

If I find my element with: `field_options = @browser.driver.find_element(:id => 'searchFieldOptions')`

I can get the Selenium element:
`"#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x671e64fc531f7284 id=\"758f274f-c4f1-40d7-a7eb-b472705361e7\">"`

I can work with this, but life would be easier if I could locate the element(s) just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, color me embarrassed.
I thought I had tried this already, but either i didn't or had a typo or?

Anyhow, once I find my element: `my_watir_element.wd` gives me what I need.

Comment: Yes, this is the way!